# Adding markers and polyline to a google map with a event.trigger to mimic a click works different than an actual click

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to update a google map with google.maps.DirectionsService and  google.maps.Polyline. The map may be empty on initiation, or start with coordinates from an array.

When the map is empty, each location the user click will become a marker, and there will be a polyline path drawn between the markers, and the path will be adjusted as a user deletes markers.

It all works well when using the click event handler on a manual mouse click.

The problem is when I try to populate the map with markers created by coordinates from the array.
I am trying to simply put the marker latlng coordinates in with an array and iterate through the array doing the same thing as if someone was clicking the map.

I tried it both iterating through the array with the same code as clicking, as well as even iterating through the array to mimic a click event, calling the same function as if clicking on the map.

For some reason, when I do it manually clicking, the code runs like I expect. When I run it iterating through the array, the order of the code is somehow messed up and the markers show up, but the polyline path is drawing too many lines, connecting too many points.

I am new to JavaScript other than very simple DOM manipulation so I suspect it has something to do with the async functions used by the google maps API which I do not fully understand. I tried to use "await" where I could think to. I am not sure if I am using them correctly, but like I say, it works when I click on the map.

Thinking that perhaps the array is too fast for the API to keep up, I put in a timer to slow it down between iterations, but it still turns out differently.

Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #map {height: 600px;width: 100%;}
    .log {margin: 0 0 0 0;padding: 0 0 0 0;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <button id="delete-marker">Delete Marker</button>
  <pre id="markersAndPaths"></pre>
  <div id="log"></div>
  <script>

    let map;
    let polyline;
    let directionsService;
    let markers = [];
    let sections = [];
    let fullPath = []; 
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    let default_markers = [
        [36.92137740132106, 138.44167498874666],
        [36.9201679950352, 138.44216315078737],
        [36.92008222081132, 138.43934683132173],
    ]
    function initMap() {
        mapOptions = {
            center: { lat: 36.921, lng: 138.443 },
            zoom: 17,
            scrollwheel: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        polyline = new google.maps.Polyline();
        let debug;
        //debug = 1000;
    if (debug > 0) {
        
        for (var i = 0; i < default_markers.length; i++) {
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(default_markers[i][0], default_markers[i][1]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: position,
                 map: map
            });
            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
            map.panTo(map.getCenter());
            markers.push(marker);
            marker.id = markers.length
            
            if (markers.length > 1) {
                doclog(`call polyline m${markers.length}: s${sections.length}`)
                updatePolyLine();
                doclog(``, 'hr')
            }
        }
    }

        map.addListener('click', function(event) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: event.latLng,
                map: map
            });
            doclog(`markers.length: ${markers.length} event.latlng:${event.latLng}`)
            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
            map.panTo(map.getCenter());
            markers.push(marker);
            marker.id = markers.length
            if (markers.length > 1) {
                doclog(`call polyline  m${markers.length}: s${sections.length}`)
                updatePolyLine();
                doclog(``, 'hr')
            }
        });
        
        for (var x = 0; x < default_markers.length; x++) {
            const latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(default_markers[x][0], default_markers[x][1]);
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'click', {latLng: latLng});
            //while (new Date().getTime() < start + 1000);  
        }

        document.getElementById('delete-marker').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            var undone = markers.pop();
            if (markers.length > 0) {
                map.setCenter(markers[markers.length-1].getPosition());
                map.panTo(map.getCenter());
            }
            sections.pop();
            sections.pop();
            undone.setMap(null);
            if (markers.length > 0) {
                updatePolyLine();
            }
        });
    }

    async function updatePolyLine() {
        fullPath = [];
        doclog(`Insdie updatePolyLine: Markers: ${markers.length}`)
        for (var i = 1; i < markers.length; i++) {
            doclog(`${i} < ${markers.length} (i < maerkers.length)`)
            console.log(`${i} < ${markers.length}`);
            if (i == markers.length - 1) {

                doclog(`${i} == ${markers.length - 1} (i == markers.length - 1)`)
                var start = markers[i-1].getPosition()
                var end = markers[i].getPosition()
                var section_id = `${markers[i-1].id}-${markers[i].id}`;
                let section = {
                        'id': section_id,
                        'start_id': markers[i-1].id,
                        'start': start,
                        'end_id': markers[i].id,
                        'end': end,
                        'waypoints': []
                    }
                sections.push(section);
                doclog(`sections.push(${section.id}); sections.length ${sections.length} (i == markers.length - 1)`)
             }  
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < (sections.length); i++) {
            doclog(` .   Inside sections loop: ${i} < ${sections.length}: (i < (sections.length))`)
            doclog(`id = ${sections[i].id} of ${sections.length}`)
            if (sections[i].waypoints == '') {
                await getRoute(sections[i], sections[i].start, sections[i].end)
            } 
            doclog(` .   ----- push to fullpath ------`)
            fullPath.push(sections[i].waypoints);
        }
                
        polyline.setPath(fullPath.flat());
        polyline.setMap(map)

        logMarkersAndSections()
        
        function updateSection(response, section) {
            var path = []
            for (var i = 0, len = response.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
                path.push(response.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
                console.log(`start_id ${section.start_id} ${response.routes[0].overview_path[i]}`)
            }
            section.waypoints = path;
        }

        async function getRoute(section, start, end) {
            doclog(`Call getRoute sections[${i}](${sections[i]}, ${sections[i].start},${sections[i].end})`)
            var routeOptions = {
                    origin: section.start,
                    destination: section.end,
                    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
            }
            await directionsService.route(routeOptions)
                .then(async function(response) {
                   await updateSection(response, section);
            });   
            doclog(`GOT Route sections[${i}](${sections[i]}, ${sections[i].start},${sections[i].end})`)
                
        };  
    };

    window.initMap = initMap;
  </script>




<script>

    function doclog(data, tag) {
        var stack = new Error().stack;
        var lines = stack.split('\n');
        var lineNumber = lines[2].match(/(\d+):(\d+)/);;
        tag ||= 'p';
        var div = document.getElementById("log");
        var element = document.createElement(tag);
        element.classList.add("log");
        element.innerHTML = (`[${lineNumber[0]}] ${data}`);
        div.appendChild(element);
    }

    function logFullPath() {
        out = `${fullPath}`
        document.getElementById("fullPath").innerHTML = out.replace(/,\(/g, ",\n(");
    }

    function logMarkersAndSections() {
        out = `markers<br>`;
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            out += `[${i}] : ${markers[i].position}<br>`
        }
        out += `Sections<br>`;
        for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
            out += `[${i}] : (${sections[i].id}) : ${sections[i].start} -> ${sections[i].end}<br>`
        }
        document.getElementById("markersAndPaths").innerHTML = out;
    }

  </script>

<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[apikey]&callback=initMap">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is some of the logging I got the first one is when I click three points on the map manually using the click event by clicking with a mouse:

```
markers
[0] : (36.921849150345615, 138.442817609787)
[1] : (36.92006506595496, 138.4419914894104)
[2] : (36.919876362280334, 138.44024805355073)
Sections
[0] : (1-2) : (36.921849150345615, 138.442817609787) -> (36.92006506595496, 138.4419914894104)
[1] : (2-3) : (36.92006506595496, 138.4419914894104) -> (36.919876362280334, 138.44024805355073)
[67:13] markers.length: 0 event.latlng:(36.921849150345615, 138.442817609787)
[67:13] markers.length: 1 event.latlng:(36.92006506595496, 138.4419914894104)
[76:17] call polyline m2: s0
[105:9] Insdie updatePolyLine: Markers: 2
[107:13] 1 < 2 (i < maerkers.length)
[111:17] 1 == 1 (i == markers.length - 1)
[124:17] sections.push(1-2); sections.length 1 (i == markers.length - 1)
[129:13] . Inside sections loop: 0 < 1: (i < (sections.length))
[130:13] id = 1-2 of 1
[154:13] Call getRoute sections[0]([object Object], (36.921849150345615, 138.442817609787),(36.92006506595496, 138.4419914894104))
[78:17
[164:13] GOT Route sections[0]([object Object], (36.921849150345615, 138.442817609787),(36.92006506595496, 138.4419914894104))
[134:13] . ----- push to fullpath ------
[67:13] markers.length: 2 event.latlng:(36.919876362280334, 138.44024805355073)
[76:17] call polyline m3: s1
[105:9] Insdie updatePolyLine: Markers: 3
[107:13] 1 < 3 (i < maerkers.length)
[107:13] 2 < 3 (i < maerkers.length)
[111:17] 2 == 2 (i == markers.length - 1)
[124:17] sections.push(2-3); sections.length 2 (i == markers.length - 1)
[129:13] . Inside sections loop: 0 < 2: (i < (sections.length))
[130:13] id = 1-2 of 2
[134:13] . ----- push to fullpath ------
[129:13] . Inside sections loop: 1 < 2: (i < (sections.length))
[130:13] id = 2-3 of 2
[154:13] Call getRoute sections[1]([object Object], (36.92006506595496, 138.4419914894104),(36.919876362280334, 138.44024805355073))
[78:17]
[164:13] GOT Route sections[1]([object Object], (36.92006506595496, 138.4419914894104),(36.919876362280334, 138.44024805355073))
[134:13] . ----- push to fullpath ------
```

The second one is when I iterate through the default_array to call  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'click', {latLng: latLng});

Everything is the same up until it gets to where the manually clicked markers retrieves a Route Section and pushes it into the fullpath[]. The iterated markers skips that and calls the updatePolyLine() function.

```
markers
[0] : (36.92137740132106, 138.44167498874666)
[1] : (36.9201679950352, 138.44216315078737)
[2] : (36.92008222081132, 138.43934683132173)
Sections
[0] : (1-2) : (36.92137740132106, 138.44167498874666) -> (36.9201679950352, 138.44216315078737)
[1] : (2-3) : (36.9201679950352, 138.44216315078737) -> (36.92008222081132, 138.43934683132173)
[67:13] markers.length: 0 event.latlng:(36.92137740132106, 138.44167498874666)
[67:13] markers.length: 1 event.latlng:(36.9201679950352, 138.44216315078737)
[76:17] call polyline m2: s0
[105:9] Insdie updatePolyLine: Markers: 2
[107:13] 1 < 2 (i < maerkers.length)
[111:17] 1 == 1 (i == markers.length - 1)
[124:17] sections.push(1-2); sections.length 1 (i == markers.length - 1)
[129:13] . Inside sections loop: 0 < 1: (i < (sections.length))
[130:13] id = 1-2 of 1
[154:13] Call getRoute sections[0]([object Object], (36.92137740132106, 138.44167498874666),(36.9201679950352, 138.44216315078737))
[78:17
[67:13] markers.length: 2 event.latlng:(36.92008222081132, 138.43934683132173)
[76:17] call polyline m3: s1
[105:9] Insdie updatePolyLine: Markers: 3
[107:13] 1 < 3 (i < maerkers.length)
[107:13] 2 < 3 (i < maerkers.length)
[111:17] 2 == 2 (i == markers.length - 1)
[124:17] sections.push(2-3); sections.length 2 (i == markers.length - 1)
[129:13] . Inside sections loop: 0 < 2: (i < (sections.length))
[130:13] id = 1-2 of 2
[154:13] Call getRoute sections[0]([object Object], (36.92137740132106, 138.44167498874666),(36.9201679950352, 138.44216315078737))
[78:17]
[164:13] GOT Route sections[0]([object Object], (36.92137740132106, 138.44167498874666),(36.9201679950352, 138.44216315078737))
[134:13] . ----- push to fullpath ------
[129:13] . Inside sections loop: 1 < 2: (i < (sections.length))
[130:13] id = 2-3 of 2
[154:13] Call getRoute sections[1]([object Object], (36.9201679950352, 138.44216315078737),(36.92008222081132, 138.43934683132173))
[164:13] GOT Route sections[0]([object Object], (36.92137740132106, 138.44167498874666),(36.9201679950352, 138.44216315078737))
[134:13] . ----- push to fullpath ------
[129:13] . Inside sections loop: 1 < 2: (i < (sections.length))
[130:13] id = 2-3 of 2
[154:13] Call getRoute sections[1]([object Object], (36.9201679950352, 138.44216315078737),(36.92008222081132, 138.43934683132173))
[164:13] GOT Route sections[1]([object Object], (36.9201679950352, 138.44216315078737),(36.92008222081132, 138.43934683132173))
[134:13] . ----- push to fullpath ------
[164:13] GOT Route sections[1]([object Object], (36.9201679950352, 138.44216315078737),(36.92008222081132, 138.43934683132173))
[134:13] . ----- push to fullpath ------
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the browser time to request, receive and render the directions segments after triggering the "click" event on the map:

```
for (var x = 0; x < default_markers.length; x++) {
    const latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(default_markers[x][0], default_markers[x][1]);
    setTimeout(function() {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'click', {latLng: latLng});
    },1000*x);  // 1 second between clicks
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/Lmkbz2s8/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
let map;
let polyline;
let directionsService;
let markers = [];
let sections = [];
let fullPath = [];
var start = new Date().getTime();
let default_markers = [
  [36.92137740132106, 138.44167498874666],
  [36.9201679950352, 138.44216315078737],
  [36.92008222081132, 138.43934683132173],
]

function initMap() {
  mapOptions = {
    center: {
      lat: 36.921,
      lng: 138.443
    },
    zoom: 17,
    scrollwheel: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  polyline = new google.maps.Polyline();

  map.addListener('click', function(event) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      map: map
    });
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    map.panTo(map.getCenter());
    markers.push(marker);
    marker.id = markers.length
    if (markers.length > 1) {
      updatePolyLine();
    }
  });

  for (var x = 0; x < default_markers.length; x++) {
    const latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(default_markers[x][0], default_markers[x][1]);
    setTimeout(function() {
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'click', {
        latLng: latLng
      });
    }, 1000 * x);
  }

  document.getElementById('delete-marker').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var undone = markers.pop();
    if (markers.length > 0) {
      map.setCenter(markers[markers.length - 1].getPosition());
      map.panTo(map.getCenter());
    }
    sections.pop();
    sections.pop();
    undone.setMap(null);
    if (markers.length > 0) {
      updatePolyLine();
    }
  });
}

async function updatePolyLine() {
  fullPath = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < markers.length; i++) {
    if (i == markers.length - 1) {

      var start = markers[i - 1].getPosition()
      var end = markers[i].getPosition()
      var section_id = `${markers[i-1].id}-${markers[i].id}`;
      let section = {
        'id': section_id,
        'start_id': markers[i - 1].id,
        'start': start,
        'end_id': markers[i].id,
        'end': end,
        'waypoints': []
      }
      sections.push(section);
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < (sections.length); i++) {
    if (sections[i].waypoints == '') {
      await getRoute(sections[i], sections[i].start, sections[i].end)
    }
    fullPath.push(sections[i].waypoints);
  }

  polyline.setPath(fullPath.flat());
  polyline.setMap(map)

  function updateSection(response, section) {
    var path = []
    for (var i = 0, len = response.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
      path.push(response.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
    }
    section.waypoints = path;
  }

  async function getRoute(section, start, end) {
    var routeOptions = {
      origin: section.start,
      destination: section.end,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }
    await directionsService.route(routeOptions)
      .then(async function(response) {
        await updateSection(response, section);
      });
  };
};

window.initMap = initMap;
```

```css
#map {
  height: 80%;
}


/* 
 * Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. 
 */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Directions Service</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <button id="delete-marker">Delete Marker</button>
  <pre id="markersAndPaths"></pre>
  <div id="log"></div>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&v=weekly" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you.

Can I ask though why that works differently than what i had tried previously:
    for (var i = 0; i < default_markers.length; i++) {var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(default_markers[i][0], default_markers[i][1]);
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'click', {latLng: latLng});
    while (new Date().getTime() < start + 1000);  
    }

I had tried setTimeout() and "while (new Date().getTime() < start + 1000 * i);" in various places in the program, but even doing it like I show above it did not work. 

Why? Aren't they both waiting in between triggering the click?

Comment: Hard to say as you didn't provide any [mvce] demonstrating those attempts.  The  `while (new Date().getTime() < start + 1000); }` doesn't free up the processor/browser like a `setTimeout` does.